# CSS - How can I display my small template posts next to each other

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, ejs, css-grid

I have tried many different ways, how I can display them next to each other, but the problem is they are still displaying above/under one and other towards the left part of the page, how can I do so that they display next to each other, I am gonna post the CSS part that's relevant to the posts.ejs file. I wanna use maybe Grid or Flex for that!

admin.css

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.grid .post {
    border: 4px dashed #207420;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
```

posts.ejs

```html
    <main>
        <% if (posts.length > 0) { %>

        <% for (let post of posts) { %>

        <div class="grid">
                <article class="post">
                    <h1><%=post.title%></h1>
                    <p><%=post.description%></p>
                    <a href="/post/<%=post._id%>">See Post</a>
                <article>

        </div>

        <% } %>
        <%  } else { %>

        <h1>No Posts Found</h1>
        <% } %>
    </main>
```

Comment: In the code that you are running, did you forget to end article? `</article>`?

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are creating div with class grid for each post

Insead use your for loop inside your div with class grid

```
  <main>
        <% if (posts.length > 0) { %>


        <div class="grid">

            <% for (let post of posts) { %>

                <article class="post">
                    <h1><%=post.title%></h1>
                    <p><%=post.description%></p>
                    <a href="/post/<%=post._id%>">See Post</a>
                <article>

            <% } %>
        </div>


        <%  } else { %>

        <h1>No Posts Found</h1>
        <% } %>
    </main>
```